# Difference between require('module')() and const mod = require('module') mod() in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pouchdb

I have two files: `server.js` and `db.js`

`server.js` looks as such:

```
...
const app = express();

app.use('/db', db());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000')
});
...
```

and `db.js` as such:

```
...
function init() {
  const db = require('express-pouchdb')(PouchDB, {
    mode: 'minimumForPouchDB'
  });

  return db;
}
...
```

This works just fine, and I am able to reach the pouchdb http-api from my frontend. But before, I had `const PouchDBExpress = require('pouchdb-express');` in the top of `db.js`, and the first line in `init()` looked like this; `const db = PouchDBExpress(PouchDB, {`. This gave an error in one of the internal files in pouchdb saying `cannot set property query on req which only has getters` (paraphrasing).

So this made me copy the exaples from pouchdb-servers GitHub examples which requires and invokes `pouched-express` directly, and everthing worked fine. Is there an explanation for this? I'm glad it works now, but I'm sort of confused as to what could cause this.

Comment: Show us where `init` is called, please - that might make the actual difference. (Although it indeed shouldn't. You might want to file a bug with the library)

Comment: `express-pouchdb`, `pouchdb-express` or `pouched-express`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between:

```
require('module')()
```

and

```
const mod = require('module');
mod();
```

is that in the second case, you retain a reference to the module exports object (perhaps for other uses) whereas in the first one you do not.

Both cases load the module and then call the exported object as a function.  But, if the module export has other properties or other methods that you need access to then, obviously, you need to retain a reference to it as in the second option.

For us to comment in more detail about the code scenario that you said did not work, you will have to show us that exact code scenario.  Describing what is different in words rather than showing the actual code makes it too hard to follow and impossible to spot anything else you may have inadvertently done wrong to cause your problem.

Comment: Thanks!

It is as I thought then regarding retaining the reference in the second scenario. But is there nothing else that happens in the node application when you choose to do it this way? For me it makes no sense that such a small change makes the difference for the application throwing an error or not upon a GET-request.

There is a bit more code around, which the '...' indicates, but there really was no other change to the code other than invoking the exported module directly instead of storing it in a variable and then invoking. It baffled me when quite a bit when it "suddenly" worked.

Comment: @ChristerOlsen - There is nothing else node.js will do differently.  There is likely something different in your code (such as the timing of when you load things) that is causing a difference.

Comment: @ChristerOlsen - If your question has been answered, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most.  That will also earn you some reputation points on stack overflow for following the proper procedure.

Comment: Yeah, must have been. Didn't make branch or commit to mark the code difference (which I should have), and the code no longer looks anything like it did when the weirdness occurred. Thanks for the input though! If i ever get the same error again, I'll post the _actual_ code.

Comment: Might have been some express 5.x alpha bug too. Ran into a few other issues with it, and have since downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

In **require('module')()**, you don't retain a reference of the module imported.

While in **const mod = require('module'); mod()**, you retain a reference and can use the same reference later in your code.

This problem might be due to some other reason like -

1. Are you using a some another global instance of the db, and your code works in the given case as you are making a local instance
2. Some other code dependent scenario.

Please provide more details for the same